# IF MATCH SHOW RESULT IF NOT ""

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, match, nested-if

I'm trying to do a Match for values in a column there is a name and then the corresponding ID, in a part I have the list only for ID so I have to match the name, and I'm using this formula:

```
=INDEX(MATCH!$A$2:$A$400,MATCH(B2,MATCH!$B$2:$B$400,0))
```

But with empty values (this is a dynamic document) Show me #N/A so I would like something like
THIS

`=IF(VALUE=VALUE EXISTS, SHOW VALUE, "")`

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can wrap it into `IFNA` formula and not define it:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(MATCH!$A$2:$A$400,MATCH(B2,MATCH!$B$2:$B$400,0)))
```